# Scala - generic method parameter that must extend multiple base type

Tags: scala, generics

I would like to have a method with a parameter that implements 2 interfaces, an example could be seen following:

```
  def autoClose[T <: AutoCloseable, A](closeable: T)(cb: T => A): A = {
    try {
      cb(closeable)
    } finally {
      closeable.close()
    }
  }

  def autoFlush[T <: Flushable, A](flushable: T)(cb: T => A): A = {
    try {
      cb(flushable)
    } finally {
      flushable.flush()
    }
  }
```

It would logical to have a method like:

```
  def autoFlushClose[T <: Flushable <: AutoCloseable, A](value: T)(cb: T => A): A = {
    autoClose(value) { value =>
      autoFlush(value)(cb)
    }
  }
```

How do I define that `T` type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [compound types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/compound-types.html):

```scala
def autoFlushClose[T <: Flushable with AutoCloseable, A](
    value: T
)(cb: T => A): A = {
  autoClose(value) { value =>
    autoFlush(value)(cb)
  }
}
```

Or Scala 3 version:

```scala
def autoFlushClose[T <: Flushable & AutoCloseable, A](
    value: T
)(cb: T => A): A = {
  autoClose(value) { value =>
    autoFlush(value)(cb)
  }
}
```